# Event Meeting Request functionlity but without sending the invite

Tags: activities, event

I want to plan an event and know when some people are available so I do not want to send the invite out, I just want to add their availability.

Is it possible to have the availability of event attendees show without inviting them?  ie set it for them manually with no email.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.  Meeting Requests don't have the ability to create a "draft" meeting request that would let you view everyone's availability without sending an email, unless you want to recreate the meeting request ever time.

However, if you can get by the with the less fully functioned event availability tools you can get pretty close to what you're looking for.  Create an event and add the invitees and instead of clicking 'Save and Send Update' click the plain 'Save' button.  The event will show up on your invitees calendars as waiting for their response, but they won't get an email.  And when you go back and edit the event you can see a list of the attendees with their availability for the day of the event.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to this information, I would like your readers to check the appexchange native app - Click.meet which is:
1. One click and you can start a meeting with a lead or contact
2. Schedule meetings and add attendees right within Salesforce
3.Sync event/task with google calender and also get meeting update in ical for outlook users. 
4. Associate meetings with any standard objects or custom objects in Salesforce
5. Auto sync GoToMeeting meetings and attendees with Salesforce even if they are created in GoToMeeting directly
6.Sync past meetings,Attendees and also can edit with/without informing to attendees

Check this link:
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3a8cEAB

Thanks
A P

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is going to vary from org to org and how the org's calendaring is set-up. Unless calendars are shared, the answer is no.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what the question was asking.

Comment: Could very well be. Good insight/catch and excellent response!